# Zero installation Node.js app with Redis backend

Tags: node.js, redis, node-webkit

I am using Node.js (Node-webkit) app, that I should deploy on USB stick. It depends on Redis server running in background. (Windows).

How to achieve this? So that user does not need to install Redis, just plug-and-play?

Should `require('child-process').exec('redis-server')` be enough? Then how to wait until it is fully loaded?

How to avoid antivirus/firewall issues?

Comment: What do you need redis for? It's pretty unlikely that you need that for whatever you use it currently :P

Comment: @BenA. it holds all data, mostly read-only. The texts, indexes, links, markup etc. Few GB in size.

Comment: If those the same for everyone you could use a remote redis instance and just connect to that, however that is probably not the best idea.
Think about saving your stuff differently, maybe just on the file system?
Redis is not really a solution for desktop Applications...